# Loop to save multiple frames generated

Tags: python, opencv

I am using a code that takes an input as a video file and then applies image processing (foreground segmentation) on the video. 
I am trying to save the frames processed (output) but I cannot figure out how to use a loop do to so.

```
while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame',fgmask)

    cv2.imwrite("frame.jpg", fgmask)
```

The last line of the code saves the frames. But it currently only saves the last generated output as there is no loop to save all the frames generated.

How can a loop be used to save all the files processed?

Answer (score 3):

Introducing a counter to change the file name will resolve the issue

```
cnt = 1
while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame',fgmask)

    cv2.imwrite("frame" + str(cnt) + ".jpg", fgmask)
    cnt += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can output a video of the generated frames.

```
# Open the video writer
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',-1, 1,(int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))))

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)    
    # Write the frame
    out.write(fgmask)

# Release the writer
out.release()
```